# Retrieving form data into a php processor

Tags: php

I am having a problem understanding how to make the foreach function work. I have a form, that uses check boxes. I tried loading them as an array of check boxes, but I couldn't get the foreach function to work for me. I don't properly understand all of this. Let me post my form data real quick:

```
<form method="post" action="interests.php" name="interests">

<table width="500" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#FF80FF" bordercolor="#800000">

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="4"></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check5" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check6" value="6"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check7" value="7"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check8" value="8"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Here is my php processor so far..:

```
<?php
for(x=1;x>8;x++){
    $loop=

echo 'Your interests have been updated into the database, and those files will now</br>';
echo 'begin showing up in the files area on your files sections.';
?>
```

I know, not much, because I am stuck. I am banging my head. I need to parse this out, and check for values filled, so I can input the data into a database. Seems simple enough, but for some reason I cant get it!

Comment: change the names to `name="check[1]"` etc then use  `foreach($_POST[check] as $x){...}`

Answer (score 1):

After your edit , i suggest to give all your checkbox `name='check[]'` and in your php code you will get all values of inputs that are checked in `$_POST['check']` without trying to do it manually,this code will echo all checked values :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
            echo $check.'<br/>'; //echo checked value
    }
}
?>
```

---

**First answer :**

To minimize your HTML code using php use `modulus` (`$a % $b` Modulus Remainder of `$a` divided by `$b`) to show `<tr>` element before every 4 inputs

Try this :

```
<form method="post" action="interests.php" name="interests">

<table width="500" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#FF80FF" bordercolor="#800000">

<?php
for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){

  if (($i-1)%4==0) echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check$i' value='$i'/></td>";
}
?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: Notice the cleaver use of the modulus `%`: `9 % 4 = 1`